# How to get the third level of a tree in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I aim to list the forth generation of a family using SQL Server.

Example family tree in the picture (id based)

[FAMILY TREE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpAlG.png)

The tables I have are:

**Family**

```
+------+-----------------+
| f_id | f_name          |
+------+-----------------+
| 1    | Name Surname 1  |
| 2    | Name Surname 2  |
| 3    | Name Surname 3  |
| 4    | Name Surname 4  |
| 5    | Name Surname 5  |
| 6    | Name Surname 6  |
| 7    | Name Surname 7  |
| 8    | Name Surname 8  |
| 9    | Name Surname 9  |
| 10   | Name Surname 10 |
+------+-----------------+
```

**Relations**

```
+----------+---------+
| r_parent | r_child |
+----------+---------+
| 1        | 2       |
| 1        | 3       |
| 2        | 4       |
| 2        | 5       |
| 3        | 6       |
| 3        | 7       |
| 3        | 8       |
| 7        | 9       |
| 8        | 10      |
+----------+---------+
```

This is the result I need:

```
 9 Name Surname
10 Name Surname
```

Comment: This is tricky enough and I don't do it often enough to write the full answer right now in the time I have, but I can at least give you a comment pointing you to [recursive CTEs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), which is the technique generally best suited to solving this issue.

Comment: That's one of the least efficient ways to store a hierarchical data structure in an RDBMS. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/hierarchical-data-sql-server or, for a very simple solution, look at "Nested Sets."

Comment: Agree but this is example simulate real legacy designed db and can't be redesigned (client's existing db)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to do the same join with different aliases to get the last generation**
The other option is to make recursive CTE.

```
SELECT 
    G4.*
FROM relations GR1
    INNER JOIN family G1 ON GR1.r_parent = G1.f_id
    INNER JOIN family G2 on GR1.r_child = G2.f_id
    INNER JOIN relations GR2 ON GR2.r_parent = G2.f_id
    INNER JOIN family G3 ON GR2.r_child = G3.f_id
    INNER JOIN relations GR3 ON GR3.r_parent = G3.f_id
    INNER JOIN family G4 ON GR3.r_child = G4.f_id
```

The script used is:

```
CREATE TABLE family(f_id int ,f_name nvarchar (200))
INSERT INTO family 
VALUES 
  (1, 'Name Surname 1')
, (2, 'Name Surname 2')
, (3, 'Name Surname 3')
, (4, 'Name Surname 4')
, (5, 'Name Surname 5')
, (6, 'Name Surname 6')
, (7, 'Name Surname 7')
, (8, 'Name Surname 8')
, (9, 'Name Surname 9')
, (10, 'Name Surname 10')

CREATE TABLE relations (r_parent int, r_child int)
INSERT INTO relations VALUES (1, 2), (1, 3), (2,4), (2,5), (3,6), (3,7), (3,8), (7,9), (8,10)



SELECT 
    G4.*
FROM relations GR1
    INNER JOIN family G1 ON GR1.r_parent = G1.f_id
    INNER JOIN family G2 on GR1.r_child = G2.f_id
    INNER JOIN relations GR2 ON GR2.r_parent = G2.f_id
    INNER JOIN family G3 ON GR2.r_child = G3.f_id
    INNER JOIN relations GR3 ON GR3.r_parent = G3.f_id
    INNER JOIN family G4 ON GR3.r_child = G4.f_id


DROP TABLE family
DROP TABLE relations
```

Answer (score 1):

For a fixed (and relatively small) number of levels, you can join:

```
select f.*
from relations r1
inner join relations r2 on r2.r_parent = r1.r_child
inner join relations r3 on r3.r_parent = r2.r_child
inner join family f on f.f_id = r3.r_child
where not exists (select 1 from relations r0 where r0.r_child = r1.r_parent)
```

A more generic approach uses a recursive query:

```
with cte as (
    select r.r_parent, r.r_child, 1 lvl
    from relations r
    where not exists (select 1 from relations r0 where r0.r_child = r.r_parent)
    union all 
    select r.r_parent, r.r_child, c.lvl + 1
    from relations r
    inner join cte c on c.r_child = r.r_parent
    where c.lvl < 3
)
select f.*
from family f
inner join cte c on c.r_child = f.f_id
where c.lvl = 3
```

Comment: Good thought. Here I was thinking about writing a recursive CTE, but for three known levels this is fine.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: thanks. I still offered the recursive CTE as an alternative if the number of levels gets bigger.

Comment: Both queries return nothing!

Comment: @mesutm: I had the columns inverted in the `where` clause of the `not exists` subquery. Fixed. Note: I think that the solution you accepted does not work as you want: it will happily start from the middle of the tree, and return anything that is 3 levels deeper, since there is no condition that ensures that the first joined table is the root of the tree (which is what `not exists` does in my code). Also, there are unecessary intermediate joins on `family` (we only need to join the family on the last level).